# Does anybody have any good material on TacPlus?

Tags: cisco, tacacs+

Does anybody know, either good websites or books which can help us setup a Tacacs+ (tacplus) server?

Any help would be appreciated.   Thanks

AB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read book from Cisco Press "Routing TCP/IP Volume II" by Jeff Doyle. It has one chapter on router management, including configuring tacacs+ authentication on cisco IOS and configuring the tacacs+ server.

Tacplus installation is very easy, and you can configure the server via tacplus.conf by instruction on that book.

Comment: Thanks for this, I got a copy of the book and will have a look at in detail.  I also found this material on the net url: http://www.stben.net/tacacs/users_guide.html